# User Control In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I created a user control. It contains one textbox. can I control this from parent web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following property to your user control:

```
public string SomeValue
{
    get
    {
        return txtSample.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        txtSample.Text = value;
    }
}
```

And if you want to get or set the user control's textbox value from the page that contains the user control, just do the following:

```
MyUserControl.SomeValue = "Hello from page";
lblTest.Text = MyUserControl.SomeValue;
```

Where "MyUserControl" is the ID of the user control in the containing page.

Note: Since the TextBox control handles its Text property in the ViewState on its own, you don't have to explicitly handle it for this property.

Answer (score 1):

Just define some public method or property in the user control and you can access it successfully. For example:

In UserControl1.ascx.cs:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    //Do something here from UserControl
}
```

In the parent:

```
MyInstanceOfUserControl1.DoSomething();
```

Comment: No. In post back, I want to get text in textbox of user control from parent page

Comment: than just define a public method in user control which will return Textbox1.Text value

Comment: The best answer IMO; rather than exposing the control's controls for all and sundry to manipulate, expose only the functionality you wish to be available, maybe `GetText` and `SetText`, for instance.